# Update XML on server without PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. I have a JavaScript function which should update an XML file (btw please check if its correct):

```
function changename(node2){
    var nodenumber = node2;
    var newname = "tescik";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "config2.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('device').each(function () {
                var node = $(this).find('node');
                if (node.text() == nodenumber) {
                var name = $(this).find('name').text(newname);
                    alert(name.text());
                    $.post(
                        "config2.xml",
                        {
                            name: "Bravo"
                        },
                        function(dane){
                            alert("Dane otrzymane: " + dane);
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The problem now is: How to update that file on the web server? I can not install PHP server on this. There can be only a web server. Nothing else.

Please send my any instruction or materials which can help me.

Comment: There are severals ways to eat a carrot, Javascript is not one of them...

Comment: You cannot edit random files in arbitrary web servers. The web is not that insecure.

Answer (score 3):

You can't save anything to a server without any server side technology. Either you use PHP, ASP.NET or any similar server side technology or leave it.

There must be a service on the other side dictating what to do with the file it receives. You can't just copy the file over there (if you want to, use FTP or something like that)

Just realize what it will mean if this is possible:
What if I could just change a file on your webserver. Would you like that? No, of course not! At least there must be some authorization, authentication, and some software that tells where to place the file.

Comment: @user3324547: was the answer clear to you or do you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. If the server does not provide some server-side way to update a file, then you can’t do it.

Imagine if a simple JavaScript file that is executed *on the client’s machine* could modify files *on the server*. That would be highly insecure. Instead, you will need at least something that processes this change on the server itself. And it’s really recommended to add some validation there too, so that one cannot just store *anything* (for example malicious code).